# Favourite list Magento 2.4

Tags: wishlist, magento2.4.3

Is there a way to create a favorite list? I know you can use a wishlist, but that disappears when you add the product to the cart.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

This is what i see, there is no add to cart option
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2, by default, when you add a product from your wishlist to your cart, the product is automatically removed from the wishlist. However, you can modify this behavior by making some changes to your Magento 2 store settings.

After changing these steps so you can rename your Wishlist to your favorite list as per your suits. I think it will better way to do that without any customization or any extension.

One way to achieve this is by changing the configuration settings for the Wishlist module in your Magento 2 store. To do this, follow the steps below:

1. Login to the admin panel of your Magento 2 store.
2. Navigate to Stores > Configuration.
3. In the Configuration page, select Customers > Wishlist.
4. In the Wishlist section, look for the option "Move items to cart" and change its value to "No".
5. Click on the "Save Config" button to save your changes.

With this configuration change, when a customer adds a product from the wishlist to the cart, the product will not be automatically removed from the wishlist. The product will still be visible in the wishlist, and the customer can choose to remove it manually from the wishlist if they want to.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I do not have that option when I go to the customer - wishlist. will add a screenshot of what i see.